# Another stupid question on l-adic sheaves: does a generically zero constructible sheaf vanish on an open subvariety?

Tags: sheaf-theory, etale-cohomology

Suppose that the stalk of a constructible l-adic ($\mathbb{Z}_l$-adic or $\mathbb{Q}_l$-adic) etale sheaf $S$ over a generic (Zariski) point of a variety $V$ is zero. Does this imply that $S$ vanishes over an open subvariety  of $V$ (containing this generic point)? This is obviously wrong without constructibilty, and obviously true for torsion sheaves; it is not quite clear for me what happens for $l$-adic sheaves. Is it sufficient to consider $S/lS$?

Comment: Yes, because any constructible $\ell$-adic sheaf on a noetherian scheme is lisse on the constituents of a stratification. 

Comment: Sorry; could you also tell me why the fact is true for lisse sheaves?

Comment: Dear Mikhail: I'll give a reference for this important fact:  Prop. 12.10 in Chapter I of Freitag-Kiehl (where their scheme $X$ is assumed to be noetherian).  They have a small typo: $\mathcal{O}_n$ should be $\mathcal{C}_n$ on line -2 of that proof. 

Comment: Another reference would be SGA 4 1/2, Rapport, 2.5.